# Update MS excel sheet(office 2010) through ASP.NET Core console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have to update cell values in an excel sheet( office 2010) through ASP.NET CORE Console application.
NOTE: Strictly not have to use Install-Package Shaman.EPPlus.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: When I am trying to use .net classes/dll code for updating the excel, I am getting error that doesn't support ASP.NET Core 1